# Making all variables global

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

I have a function in my Python script where multiple variables are created, and I want to use them in other functions. I thought of using `global` for this but I thought it would be the incorrect way to do so.

So can anyone tell me what would be the best way to create variables in a function for other functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Organize the variables into a [class](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html). Instantiate the class in one function and then pass the instance to wherever you need it.

Rule of thumb: If making something global seems like a good solution at some point, don't do it. There is always a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a "namespace" object -- an object which functions as a namespace for the purpose of keeping your global namespace clear:

```
class namespace():
    pass

global_data=namespace()

def add_attributes(obj):
    obj.foo="bar"

add_attributes(global_data)
print (global_data.foo)  #prints "bar"
```

However, this is only marginally better than using the global keyword.  You really do want a class here as mentioned by Paul.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variables as attributes of the function.

```
def f1():
    f1.a=100
    f2.b=200

def f2():
    print(f1.a,f2.b)

f1()
f2()
```

**output:**

```
100 200
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to doing this instead of in a class?

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV It can be used if one is not good/familiar with object-oriented approach.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good place to implement a class.  This has lots of advantages.  [See Classes in the tutorials](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).