# Why does globalising a boolean not work but globalising a dictionary does

Tags: python, boolean, global-variables

This is just a question wondering why this doesn't work. I have figured out a better way, but I don't know why previously it wasn't working.

```
global mydict
mydict = {}
```

This seems to work fine, and has made the mydict dictionary global. I even print mydict and it works. However, doing this:

```
global bool
bool = False
```

Does not seem to work. If trying to print bool in my code, I get:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bool' referenced before assignment
```

So why does it work for the dictionary and not the boolean?

Oh, also, if anyone was wondering how I figured out a better way, I initialised a class and made bool global in the class by doing: self.bool = False which worked. I got it from this question: [Making all variables global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775411/making-all-variables-global)

---

EDIT: As requested, I'll post the necessary code:

```
import chatbot
global mydict
mydict = {}
global haveamessage
haveamessage = False

class MyBot(chatbot.ChatBot):
    def __init__(self, username, password, site):
        chatbot.ChatBot.__init__(self,username,password,site)

    def on_message(self, c, e):
        print mydict
        print haveamessage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = MyBot("MyUsername", "MyPassword", "MySite")
    bot.start()
```

I'll try explain this code. Pretty much the chatbot module is to allow users to create bots in wikis on Wikia, a company that allows wikis to be created which anyone can edit. On a wiki there is a chat extension where users can talk to. This script allows a bot to join the chat and do commands. on_message() goes off when someone posts something in the Chat.

So this prints:

```
{}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 146, in <module>
    bot.start()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/chatbot.py", line 371, in start
    self.on_message(self.c, e)
  File "file.py", line 12, in on_message
    print haveamessage
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'haveamessage' referenced before assignment
```

---

I'd like to clarify that the reason this isn't producing an error for all of you is because you are not in a Wikia chat. the function on_message() only runs when someone posts something in the Chat. For example, I may have:

```
def on_message(self, c, e):
    if e.text == 'hello': # e.text is what a user posts in the chat. e = event
        c.send('Hello!') # c.send simply sends back a message in the chat. c = connection
```

So when someone posts in chat hello, the Bot posts back Hello!

Comment: Please post a small, runnable code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Haidro When I run that code, I get an import error. After modifying that code to remove the error, nothing happens. After adding some code to instantiate `MyBot` and call `on_message` on it, it prints `{}` and then `False`. The error message you claim to be getting never occurs.

Comment: I have added in my code and also the error that comes up.

Comment: Yes, the module chatbot is my friends. It's just something that I'm working on.

Comment: My point was that a piece of code does not qualify as "runnable" if I need files that I don't have in order to run. However the more important point was that the code you've posted does not actually cause the error you're asking about. So basically you've left us to guess at what your real code looks like and that's just rude.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try expand the code. I'm still rather new at stack overflow.

Comment: Your expanded code still doesn't produce your alleged error. The next time before you post code, you should actually run that code (by which I mean the actual you post - not the larger code you have locally) and make sure that it produces the error you're asking about.

Comment: The reason it isn't producing an error for you is because you aren't in a Wikia chat. The function only calls when a message is left in the chat, and when someone leaves a message, the function runs, and the error appears

Comment: Are you claiming that you've actually run the exact code you've posted and that it does produce an `UnboundLocalError` for you?

Comment: Okay, then I'm sorry, but you're a liar. That code will never produce that error and that has nothing to do with not being in a chat. You'd only get that error if your function contained an assignment, which in your posted code, it does not.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. I wasn't up-to-date with my friend's chatbot module, and that is what had caused the error. Sorry about that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you've posted does not produce the error you claim it does. However using the `global` keyword outside of a function has no effect, so it's not surprising that it doesn't work like you expect.

I assume that in your real code, you're actually trying to assign to `haveamessage` inside `on_message`. If so, you need a `global` statement inside that method.

Basically the rule is: If you try to assign a global variable from within a function, you need to use the `global` keyword within that function. Otherwise you don't need the `global` keyword at all. Whether or not the variable is a boolean makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is define the global variables, but then in your function reference them so you can use them locally:

```
import chatbot
mydict = {}
haveamessage = False

class MyBot(chatbot.ChatBot):
    def __init__(self, username, password, site):
        chatbot.ChatBot.__init__(self,username,password,site)

    def on_message(self, c, e):
        global mydict
        global haveamessage
        print mydict
        print haveamessage
```

Comment: You don't need to use `global` when reading global variables - only when assigning them.

Comment: Sure, but like you said in your answer, if there is an assignment trying to be made locally, the globals need to be there. I'm just showing that the OP should remove the global keyword when assigning the original values, and then use global in the function so they can be used for whatever the OP needs and have it function as expected (the global variable changing, and not a local one).