# Calling a method from farther down the stack

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok I have a code that's basically this....

```
def create():
    #long list of print statements
    m_commands()

def get_desc():
    #print statement
    m_commands()

def m_commands():
    while close != True:
        input = input(str(">>>"))
        If inp == "close" or "quit":
            close = True
        If inp == "create":
            create()
        If inp == "describe":
            get_desc()

m_commands()
```

I need to call m_commands() in create() and get_desc() to continue continuity. Is this possible. Sorry in advance, I don't know how to put code in a spoiler thingy. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I am a beginner in coding and SO

Comment: functions in python begin with `def` and not `Def`, and if you tried it you would see it would work as you expect it to (just don't call those functions before `engine` exists)

Comment: I'm on SO on mobile. I am aware it's def and not Def... But thanks for the advice. I just wasn't paying attention to this when I asked. But when I run this code it does not work. Myfunc 1 works fine but after that everything just says not defined.

Comment: We will need to see your actual code to see what's wrong, from this pseudo-code everything should work

Comment: Updated with the important bits. Left out the fluff.

Comment: `m_commands` keeps calling functions that call `m_commands` again, you're probably getting a recursion error because of that and it has nothing to do with the order they are defined. You already have a loop, you don't need that (it seems). My advice is to ask this question again with the actual error as well as actual code

Comment: Also, `close` isn't defined the first time you run through the loop

Comment: Close is defined from the beginning. I didn't add in all imports/variables etc. Or the print statements. I don't have WiFi on laptop at the moment to copy paste the entire code

Comment: If we can't see your code / error we can't really help, because in theory everything here should work (again, until you reach the recursion limit and then you'll get an error)

Comment: Also noticing now that you're overriding `input` with `input = input(str(">>>"))` and the next time it loops it is no longer a function. It's hard to know if this part of the code is real or not though, which is why it's almost impossible to help

Answer (score -1):

```
def create():
    #long list of print statements
    print("hello")
    m_commands()

def get_desc():
    #print statement
    print("world")
    m_commands()

def m_commands():
  close=False
  while close != True:
    inp = input(str(">>>"))
    if inp == "close" or "quit":
      close = True
    if inp == "create":
      create()
    if inp == "describe":
      get_desc()

m_commands()
```

This is working for me though.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but that's only because OP didn't really ask the question well as you can see in his comments. He's getting an unrelated error

Comment: The error is... After calling create() any other input just says (input) is not defined.

Comment: @ThomasKnight. can you send the exact error. Plus did you mean `inp = input(str(">>>"))` ?

Comment: Inp = str(input(">>>"). Sorry. I think I have figured out the issue. After calling a method from input the program finishes instead of re-entering the loop. Which was the reason for m_commands() in the create and get_desc function. Which also is not bringing it back to the loop.

Comment: @ThomasKnight I hope this helps.

Comment: That looks like mine. Sorry I wish I had a way to send you the code in entirety. The difference is you call close a local variable in m_commands where I label close as a global variable in m_commands. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @ThomasKnight https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420776/why-does-globalising-a-boolean-not-work-but-globalising-a-dictionary-does

Comment: Yeah I assigned close as a local in m_command and it went even more haywaire. This is just a learning project as I'm self learning python. Maybe I should start much simpler... Lol

Comment: Update... The "or" in m_commands was the culprit. Deleted that and all works as intended